# Exception when using console window in C# (Windows form application)

Tags: c#, console

I have a program WFA that also has and command Window. I open the window with AllocConsole(); When I close the console window, I use FreeConsole(); but when I open it again with AllocConsole(); I wanna write and read from it and it throws an exeption.

The code:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

class classx
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 AllocConsole();
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeConsole();
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    public static extern bool AttachConsole();
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    public static extern bool GetConsoleWindow();
    public static bool z = false;
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine HandlerRoutine, bool Add);
    public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(uint dwControlType);
}



public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    NotifyIcon icontask;
    Icon iconone_active;
    Icon iconone_inactive;
    /*Icon icontwo;
    Icon iconthree;
    Icon iconfour;
    Icon iconfive;*/
    Thread Threadworkermy;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        iconone_active = new Icon(".../iconone_active.ico");
        iconone_inactive = new Icon(".../iconone_inactive.ico");
        icontask = new NotifyIcon();
        icontask.Icon = iconone_active;
        icontask.Visible = true;
        Threadworkermy = new Thread(new ThreadStart(checkActivityThread));
        Threadworkermy.Start();

        MenuItem Nameapp = new MenuItem("xr");
        MenuItem quitappitem = new MenuItem("quit program");
        MenuItem OpenGUI = new MenuItem("Open GUI");
        MenuItem Advancedmodewindow = new MenuItem("x");
        ContextMenu contextmenu = new ContextMenu();

        quitappitem.Click += quitappitem_click;
        OpenGUI.Click += OpenGUI_click;
        Advancedmodewindow.Click += Advancedmodewindow_click;
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add(Nameapp);
        contextmenu.MenuItems[0].Enabled = false;
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add("-");
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add(OpenGUI);
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add(Advancedmodewindow);
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add("-");
        contextmenu.MenuItems.Add(quitappitem);
        icontask.ContextMenu = contextmenu;

        icontask.Icon = iconone_active;
        icontask.Visible = true;
    }

    private void Advancedmodewindow_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classx.AllocConsole();
        Console.WriteLine("X");
        classx.FreeConsole();
    }

    private void OpenGUI_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;  
    }

    private void quitappitem_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Threadworkermy.Abort();
        icontask.Dispose();
        this.Close();
    }

    public void checkActivityThread()
    {
        try
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);   
            }
        } catch(ThreadAbortException tbe)
        {

        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }


}
```

}

Exception that it throws out 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The handle is invalid.

To those who will be saying to change the type, I can't. (it needs to be WFA application)

Comment: It doesn't look like complete code, how do you allocate console? provide code behind `classx.AllocConsole()` please

Comment: i edited the code this is whole code of program

Answer (score 1):

there seems to be an issue with destroying the consolewindow, so you could just hide it.

For hiding the window you need an additional DllImport from `user32.dll` and change the returnvalue of GetConsoleWindow to IntPtr:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
```

Now check if a console-handle already exists. If it does show the console otherwise create the consolewindow:

```
private void Advancedmodewindow_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr handle = classx.GetConsoleWindow();
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        classx.AllocConsole();
        handle = classx.GetConsoleWindow();
    }
    else
    {
        //shows the window with the given handle
        classx.ShowWindow(handle, 8);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("X");
    //hides the window with the given handle
    classx.ShowWindow(handle, 0);
}
```

---

The original solution can be found here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cdee5d88-3325-47ce-9f6b-83aa4447f8ca/console-exception-on-windows-8?forum=clr

Comment: that could work to but i found a way that it Works to